# Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V on a Mac Mini

Tags: windows, bootcamp, mac-mini

Is it possible to run Windows Server R2 with Hyper-V virtualization on a Mac Mini (via BootCamp)? I am looking for a new server for my dev enviroment. A Mac Mini would be nice since I can take it with me to a customer site.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

According to the official Hyper-V [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/system-requirements.aspx) page, in order to run it you need a processor that supports Intel-VT (Virtualization Technology). Most processors today support this, but to be sure I checked on the official Mac mini [tech specs page](http://www.apple.com/macmini/specs.html) as well as the Intel's [list of processors](http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx) that support Intel-VT.

From this, we can see that the i5 processor found on the Mac mini supports Intel-VT. I recommend upgrading the RAM if possible. Also, make sure that you are running one of the [supported operating systems](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-supported-guest-os.aspx) for Hyper-V. Hope this helps.